# How to close opening in region in ToBoundaryMesh?

Tags: regions, mesh, finite-element-method

This question is about `ToBoundaryMesh`. I want to add additional border line to close the hole in region on picture below and then fill it with use of `RegionMarker`option, to get 2 different domains and mesh it with `ToElementMesh`. Nodes on the border between these two domains needs to connect.

```
 << NDSolve`FEM`
 reg = ImplicitRegion[(x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2 >= 2, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}}]
 RegionPlot[reg]
```

[image]

```
    bm = ToBoundaryMesh[reg, "RegionHoles" -> None,
    "RegionMarker" -> {{{-1,-1},1}, {{1, 1},2}},
    "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 1];
    bm2 = ToElementMesh[bm, "RegionHoles" -> None, 
    "RegionMarker" -> {{{-1, -1}, 1}, {{1, 1},2}},
    "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 1];
    bm2["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

I managed to solve problem, with adding corner points, searching neighbouring points on border and then adding the connections, then I did `ToBoundaryMesh` again with newcoordinates and connections. My solution is complicated and maybe someone knows about simpler option, maybe it already exists inside `ToBoundaryMesh`.

```
ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> newcoordinates, 
  "BoundaryElements" -> connections, "RegionHoles" -> None];
```

I also need to transfer my problem to 3D, and there searching for this points and connecting them gets really complicated.
So basically I would just like simple way to enforce master boundary or something, in this case rectangle, or in 3D Hexahedron.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you want to do some FEA with. NDSolve does what you want automatically; it detects the discontinuity. As an example:

```
uif = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + 
      If[(x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2 >= 2, 1, 2]*u[x, y] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
   u, {x, y} \[Element] 
    ImplicitRegion[-2 <= x <= 2 && -2 <= y <= 2, {x, y}]];
```

If we look at the mesh it generated we see:

```
(mesh = uif["ElementMesh"])["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

It's a bit hard to see so we look at the boundary mesh:

```
ToBoundaryMesh[mesh]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

If you are not using `NDSolve` it's a bit harder and hackier:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
boundaryMeshGenerator[region_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{pvars, const},
  pvars = region["PredicateVariables"];
  const = {NDSolve`DiscontinuitySurface[1, 
      2 - (-1 + x)^2 - (-1 + y)^2 == 0, True]} /. 
    Thread[Rule[{x, y}, pvars]];
  ContinuationBoundaryMeshGenerator[region, 
   Flatten[{{opts}, "RegionConstraints" -> const}]]
  ]

ToBoundaryMesh[Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}], 
  "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> boundaryMeshGenerator]["Wireframe"]
```

The advance of this one is that now even the internal curve is second order accurate if you use

```
ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}], 
  "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> boundaryMeshGenerator]["Wireframe"]
```

Since there is on documented way of specifying region discontinuities, we intercept the boundary mesh generation and add an undocumented

```
NDSolve`DiscontinuitySurface[1, 2 - (-1 + x)^2 - (-1 + y)^2 == 0, True]
```

1 - means the dimension (not the embedding dimension), then comes the constraint and the third argument - I don't recall.

Using Alexei's code:

```
em = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}], 
   "RegionMarker" -> {{{-1, -1}, 1}, {{1, 1}, 2}}, 
   "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> boundaryMeshGenerator];
Show[{em["Wireframe"[
    "MeshElementStyle" -> {FaceForm[LightGray], FaceForm[LightYellow],
       FaceForm[LightRed], FaceForm[LightGreen], 
      FaceForm[LightMagenta]}]], 
  em["Wireframe"["MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Black]]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following. These are the boundary coordinates including the points where the circle crosses the square:

```
squareCoords = {{-2, -2}, {-2, 2}, {0, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 0}, {2, -2}};
```

Here are the points of the circle:

```
pts = Table[{1 + Sqrt[2]*Cos[\[CurlyPhi]], 
    1 + Sqrt[2]*Sin[\[CurlyPhi]]}, {\[CurlyPhi], 3 \[Pi]/4, 
    7 \[Pi]/4, \[Pi]/40}];
```

One can make sure that this yields the desired domain:

```
Graphics[{Line[Join[squareCoords, {{-2, -2}}]], Line[pts]}]
```

[image]

Now let us create the list of coordinates by joining these two and the list of incidents:

```
coordinates = Join[coords, pts1];
incidents = 
  Join[Join[Table[{i, i + 1}, {i, 1, 5}], {{6, 1}}], 
   Join[{{3, 7}}, 
    Table[{i, i + 1}, {i, 7, 6 + Length[pts1] - 2}], {{46, 5}}]];
```

Now one can make a boundary mesh:

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`

bm = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> coordinates, 
  "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[incidents]}]
bm["Wireframe"]
```

yielding this boundary mesh:

[image]

which looks exactly as the previous picture, as it should be. After that we can make the element mesh:

```
em = ToElementMesh[bm, "RegionMarker" -> {{{-1, -1}, 1}, {{1, 1}, 2}},
   MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1]
```

and let us now have a look at it:

```
Show[{
  em["Wireframe"[
    "MeshElementStyle" -> {FaceForm[LightGray], FaceForm[LightYellow],
       FaceForm[LightRed], FaceForm[LightGreen], 
      FaceForm[LightMagenta]}]],
  em["Wireframe"["MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Black]]
  }]
```

[image]

Done. Have fun!